# Is there a way to use "nativeWebTap" capability for Appium with Python and C#

Tags: python, c#, file-upload, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to run an Automated test using Appium with Python and I'm trying to upload a file on the site: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload

But the upload button as marked in this screenshot won't click.

[image]

I tried pass to pass the file path as a text but I would get this error "The object is in an invalid state".

I have found a solution by using Appium version 2.0.0 with the capability "nativeWebTap" set to true in Java. But these configs dont seem to work with C# and Python.

If any one could help with a sample Python / C# code to upload the file it would really help.

Thanks.

This is what I tried in Python but was not able to click the upload button or upload the file:

```
capabilities = [
    
    {
        "browserName": "Safari",
        "browserVersion": "13",
        "osVersion" : "Catalina",
        "os": "OS X ",   
        "sessionName": "grandel test",
        "buildName": BUILD_NAME,
        "nativeWebTap": "true",
        "appiumVersion": "2.0.0"

    },
]
def get_browser_option(browser):
    switcher = {
        "chrome": ChromeOptions(),
        "firefox": FirefoxOptions(),
        "edge": EdgeOptions(),
        "safari": SafariOptions(),
    }
    return switcher.get(browser, ChromeOptions())
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload")
    driver.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by.accessibilityId("Choose File").click()  
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.accessibilityId, 'Choose File'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, 'file-upload'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
           (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="file-upload"]'))).click()
    driver.find_element_by.accessibilityId("Choose File").click()           
    driver.find_element_by_id("file-upload").click()
    o = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'file-upload')
    o.send_keys("Files/On My iPhone/Chrome/sample")
    p = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="file-upload"]')
    driver.find_element_by_id("file-submit").click()
    driver.quit()
```

But nothing helped

Comment: The issue seems platform-independent here as it occurs on real devices as well as devices provided and hosted by cloud service providers. 

Currently, it's a limitation of the framework I believe.